# overwritten .bashrc restarted

Tags: ubuntu

Inadvertently I've overwritten .bashrc days ago on Ubuntu 16.04. By an empty file. And switched off since. And now when I `su` the password is not recognized.

Is there any way to make the Ubuntu work, or do I have to reinstall?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a missing/empty `.bashrc` file would invalidate a password. Something else must have changed too.

Comment: Are you trying to `su` to your account, or the root account? Remember root login is disabled by default on Ubuntu. FYI you should be able to copy a *default* `~/.bashrc` from the `/etc/skel` directory - but you will need to re-add any customizations.

Comment: It's possible you had an alias on su to use sudo -i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty unlikely that it's caused by missing `.bashrc` file.

Password that `su` command is expecting is `root` user password, which on Ubuntu is not defined. Command that you probably want is `sudo` which allows you to run commands from `root` account but authenticates with your password.

Give it a try with for example:

```
sudo whoami
```

which should ask about your password and then just print word `root`.

If you want to get back default `.bashrc` file you should be able to just copy it from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` - that's the file used to "propagate" all new users dot-files.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, the two things are independent.

.bashrc - it is a good idea to keep its copy. default /etc/skel/.bashrc is fine, but empty. My settings are gone.

su - Ubuntu's `su` account is created during istallation, but password is not assigned to it. (I kept getting 'Authentication failure' - `su` & `sudo` are different!) The below linked article has details including how to assign `su` a password. `su` entails the risk of forgetting to run `exit` once the root privileges are no more needed. `sudo` - root privileges for one CLI line only - is the preferred way in most situations.

http://www.howtogeek.com/111479/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-sudo-su/

Comment: I would take "it's a good idea to keep a copy of .bashrc" several steps further — it's a _very_ good idea to back up all of `/home` automatically and regularly.